# Google Chart "Container is not defined" when the Route changes in Angular 4

Tags: javascript, angular, charts, google-visualization, angular-routing

I'm using Google Charts with Angular 4 and I get the error `Error: Container is not defined` when I go to another route and back.

here is my component

```
ngOnInit() {

    this.service.getData().subscribe(
        res => {
            this.controlData = res;
            this.createCharts(this.year);
        }
    );

}

createCharts(resultYears: any) {
    google.charts.load('current', {'packages': ['bar']});
    google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

    function drawChart() {

      const data = new google.visualization.DataTable();

      // Declare columns
      data.addColumn('string', 'Year');
      data.addColumn('number', 'Pendiente');
      data.addColumn('number', 'En Proceso');
      data.addColumn('number', 'No Recuperada');
      data.addColumn('number', 'Recuperada');

      // Add data.
      for (const chartData of resultYears) {
        data.addRow([chartData['year'].toString(), chartData['pendiente'], chartData['enproceso'], chartData['norecuperada'], chartData['recuperada']]);
      }

      const options = {
        height: 400,
        isStacked: true,
        vAxis: {format: 'decimal'},
        hAxis: {format: ''},
        series: {
          0: {color: '#fdd835'},
          1: {color: '#0091ff'},
          2: {color: '#e53935'},
          3: {color: '#43a047'},
        }
      };

      const chart = new google.charts.Bar(document.getElementById('initial_chart_div'));

      chart.draw(data, google.charts.Bar.convertOptions(options));

    }
  }
```

here is my html

```
<div id="initial_chart_div"></div>
```

everything works without problems and I can see the Chart, but If I'm in /ChartUrl and I move to /AnotherUrl and I Back to /ChartUrl I get the error `Error: Container is not defined`

Thanks for read.

P.S.: `console.log(document.getElementById('initial_chart_div'))` is always null except in `function drawChart()`

Comment: Seems like the problem is with your html. Are you using a template in your component? Can you post the rest of your code or better a plunkr?

Comment: @GordonMohrin I did this to simulate my code https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-g6zqa3 but here it works without problems

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solve it with `setTimeout` inside `drawChart` function

```
function drawChart() {

      setTimeout(() => {
        data = new google.visualization.DataTable();

        // Declare columns
        data.addColumn('string', 'Año');
        data.addColumn('number', 'Pendiente');
        data.addColumn('number', 'En Proceso');
        data.addColumn('number', 'No Recuperada');
        data.addColumn('number', 'Recuperada');
        data.addColumn('number', 'Presentada');

        // Add data.
        for (const chartData of context.year) {
          data.addRow([chartData['año'].toString(), chartData['pendiente'], chartData['enproceso'], chartData['norecuperada'], chartData['recuperada'], chartData['presentada']]);
        }

        chart = new google.charts.Bar(context.chartDiv.nativeElement);
        chart.draw(data, google.charts.Bar.convertOptions(options));

        google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'select', () => {
          const selection = chart.getSelection()[0];

          if (selection && selection.row !== null) {
            const row = selection.row;
            const column = selection.column;
            data.getValue(row, 0);
            data.getColumnLabel(column);

            context.dataGridGrupoEstado.selected = context.arrGrupoEstado.filter(me => me.grupoEstado === data.getColumnLabel(column).toLowerCase());
            context.dataGridYear.selected = context.arrYears.filter(ye => ye.year.toString() === data.getValue(row, 0));
            context.drawGridYear(parseInt(data.getValue(row, 0), 10));
            context.router.navigate(['/control de recuperos'], { queryParams: { year: context.dataGridYear.selected[0].year, grupoE: context.dataGridGrupoEstado.selected[0].grupoEstado }});
          }
        });
      }, 10);
```